# removeAttribute removes all other classes associated with element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `removeAttribute()` to remove *one* specific class attribute from an element. The problem is that `removeAttribute()` seems to remove *all* of the other defined class attributes on the element.

Example:

HTML

```
<span id="click">Click</span>
<div id="box" class="blue dotted width-50"></div>
```

CSS

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.dotted {
  border: thin dotted grey;
}

.width-50 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
var el = document.getElementById('click');
el.addEventListener("click", removeColor, false);


function removeColor() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.removeAttribute('class', 'blue');
}
```

How can I just remove the one class attribute from the element, without affecting the other class attributes on the element?

http://jsbin.com/xoxodezeze/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
function removeColor() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.classList.remove('blue');
}
```

The problem is that `removeAttribute()` removes the complete attribute name `class`
SO `<div id="box" class="blue dotted width-50"></div>`
becomse like `<div id="box" ></div>`.

You just want to remove the class here is doc
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList